# Delete X olderdays Files from Shared Folder windows batch

Tags: windows, file, batch-file, command-line, directory

I want to delete  15 days old files from the shared folder using windows command line ,

Example ::

```
Set Shared_root=\\server\folder /* Does not work for this input , how can i make this work ?*/

Set shared_root=c:\folder     /*Works for this input */

FORFILES /p %shared_root% /d -15 /c "cmd /c ECHO /S /Q @path" >NUL 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`robocopy`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145.aspx) like this:

(You can use the `/l` switch to first list the files with robocopy to avoid accidents)

```
C:\> set _robodel=%TEMP%\~robodel
C:\> MD %_robodel%
C:\> ROBOCOPY "C:\source_folder" %_robodel% /move /minage:15
C:\> del %_robodel% /q
```

[Source](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-delolder.html).